# Flutter iOS Build Error: framework not found Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am able to run the app in android studios but whenever I try in xcode I get a flutter framework not found.

Comment: This question doesn't contain any information that would allow to diagnose your problem. Check https://stackoverflow.com/help about how to ask good questions. **At least** add the full and exact error message(s) you get to your question.

Comment: thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 7):

upgrade your flutter by doing

```
flutter upgrade
```

and it will upgrade the engine and download necessary tools.

This will even kill flutter daemons.

And run the application again

```
flutter run
```

Comment: only working solution for problem !!

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure you open .xcworkspace (and not .xcodeproj in XCode).
2. Ensure you have 'Flutter.Framework' listed under "Linked Frameworks and Libraries". If not, just drag and drop it from the main project. Like below 
   [image]

Comment: What if it isn't appearing on both?

Comment: yeah i have the same issue.

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris i have the exact same problem. how did you solve it?

Comment: I have a same issue @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris  did you find any solution for it

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris Actually these frameworks should not be there anymore - so that's absolutely ok that u don't see them. Migration guide - https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ios-project-migration. In my case I had this error because I opened my project via .xcodeproj instead of .xcworkspace.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same error whene I try to archive in Xcode
I fixed it by

```
flutter upgrade
```

and

```
flutter run
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me, specially when archiving a build!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by switching to the master channel, and switching back to the stable channel. Also remember to run 'flutter upgrade' after switching.

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete the flutter directory.
2. Download new flutter
3. Extract it and put it where you want.
4. Run the command `` export PATH="$PATH:`pwd`/flutter/bin" ``
   if the command does not work then specify your path like bellow

   `export PATH="$PATH: /Users/{your user name}/Documents/src/flutter/bin"`

Restart your machine and you are ready to go.

After that - inside your project's ios directory -

1. delete the .symlink directory
2. delete the Pods directory
3. delete the Podfile.lock file

and now run -

1. `flutter clean`
2. `flutter packages upgrade`
3. `flutter build ios`

Answer (score 0):

For me nothing worked except, deleting my flutter files fully and reinstalling.

Use this flutter docs for reinstallation: [Flutter Installation Link](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install)

Comment: Giving links is fine, but please provide more detail for further information

Comment: Sir there is no more info to give. That's all that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything nothing worked except:-

Flutter upgrade
Flutter run

and boom- Build succeeded!

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following steps:

1. Delete the flutter SDK
2. Download the same flutter SDK and re-install it
3. restart the android studio
   It should be worked well.

Answer (score -3):

Fixed by switching branches from beta to master